# Spring Security Authentication with ldap fail when I use a custom login

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

when I use my custom login form I receive a message with Bad Credentials, but when I try to use the default form it works.

This is my configuration regarding to what I said

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll();
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .ldapAuthentication()
                .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
                .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
                .contextSource(contextSource())
                .passwordCompare()
                .passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder())
                .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource() {
        return new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(Arrays.asList("ldap://localhost:8389/"), "dc=springframework,dc=org");
    }
}
```

This is my login page

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title> Spring 4 Security + Thymeleaf Integration Example </title>
</head>
<body>
<h3> Spring 4 Security + Thymeleaf Integration Example </h3>
<p th:if="${param.error}">
    Bad Credentials
</p>
<form th:action="@{/login}" method="POST">
    User Name : <input type="text" name="app_username"/> <br/><br/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="app_password"/> <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my ldif file.
test-server.ldif

```
dn: dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: domain
objectclass: extensibleObject
dc: springframework

dn: ou=groups,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: groups

dn: ou=subgroups,ou=groups,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: subgroups

dn: ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: people

dn: ou=space cadets,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: space cadets

dn: ou=\"quoted people\",dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: "quoted people"

dn: ou=otherpeople,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: otherpeople

dn: uid=ben,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Ben Alex
sn: Alex
uid: ben
userPassword: {SHA}nFCebWjxfaLbHHG1Qk5UU4trbvQ=

dn: uid=bob,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Bob Hamilton
sn: Hamilton
uid: bob
userPassword: bobspassword

dn: uid=joe,ou=otherpeople,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Joe Smeth
sn: Smeth
uid: joe
userPassword: joespassword

dn: cn=mouse\, jerry,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Mouse, Jerry
sn: Mouse
uid: jerry
userPassword: jerryspassword

dn: cn=slash/guy,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: slash/guy
sn: Slash
uid: slashguy
userPassword: slashguyspassword

dn: cn=quote\"guy,ou=\"quoted people\",dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: quote\"guy
sn: Quote
uid: quoteguy
userPassword: quoteguyspassword

dn: uid=space cadet,ou=space cadets,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Space Cadet
sn: Cadet
uid: space cadet
userPassword: spacecadetspassword



dn: cn=developers,ou=groups,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
cn: developers
ou: developer
uniqueMember: uid=ben,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
uniqueMember: uid=bob,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org

dn: cn=managers,ou=groups,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
cn: managers
ou: manager
uniqueMember: uid=ben,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
uniqueMember: cn=mouse\, jerry,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org

dn: cn=submanagers,ou=subgroups,ou=groups,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
cn: submanagers
ou: submanager
uniqueMember: uid=ben,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
```

application.properties

```
spring.ldap.embedded.ldif=classpath:test-server.ldif
spring.ldap.embedded.base-dn=dc=springframework,dc=org
spring.ldap.embedded.port=8389
server.port=8082
```

I do not know what to add in addition to working....

Answer (score 0):

it could be because of configuration. you have

> .passwordAttribute("userPassword");

that means the framework is waiting for a parameter whose name is userPassword, while in your login form you are posting app_password.
Maybe the correct configuration should be

```
.usernameParameter("app_username")
.passwordParameter("app_password")
```